# How to make a cold Single 'hot' in RxJava

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactivex

I have some code that makes network requests and returns a `Single` for each.

```
public Single<Response> getSomeData(String endpoint)    
{
    return Single.fromCallable(makeNewRequest(endpoint));
}
```

This works as long as the caller actually `subscribes()` to the returned `Single`. However in some specific cases (for POST requests), the caller is not interested in the result, and never calls `subscribe()`.

Since `fromCallable()` defers execution until subscription time, this means the request will not actually be executed.

Question: What is the proper (idiomatic) way to turn this (cold) `Single` into a hot one, so that the network request is executed right away, regardless of whether the caller calls `subscribe()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally solved this by using `Single.cache()` and subscribing a dummy observer. This way the request is executed regardless of whether the API client actually subscribes to the returned observable. The code looks like this:

```
public Single<Response> getSomeData(String endpoint)    
{
    Single<Response> res = Single.fromCallable(makeNewRequest(endpoint))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // if needed
        .cache();
    res.subscribe(dummyObserver);
    return res;
}

private static final SingleObserver<Response> dummyObserver = new SingleObserver<Response>() {
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) { }
    public void onSuccess(Response s) { }
    public void onError(Throwable e) { }
};
```

**Update:**

Here's another approach that does not need the dummy observer object:

```
public Single<Response> getSomeData(String endpoint)    
{
    Single<Response> res = Single.fromCallable(makeNewRequest(endpoint))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); // if needed

    SingleSubject subject = SingleSubject.create(); 
    res.subscribe(subject);
    return subject;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you need the [`publish`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/publish.html) operator combined with [`connect`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html). Before that, you'll need to convert the `Single` into an `Observable` with [`toObservable()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html)

Also, beware that if the caller is not interested in the actual result maybe a [`Completable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html) suites better. You can convert a `Single` to a `Completable` with `toCompletable()`

Comment: There is no `Single.publish()`.

Comment: My fault. A `toObservable()` invocation is needed. I updated my answer

Comment: Not sure if this will work. If I understand correctly, by calling publish + connect before returning the Observable to the caller, then if the caller chooses to subscribe, the result may have already been emitted (and would be missed)...

Comment: Well, if you want to ignore the result sometimes and not ignore it some other times... Either you delegate that logic to the caller or check the [`BehaviourSubject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `SingleSubject` to cache the response for any interested party, but note that you have to add scheduling and possibly cancellation to this API call in some way:

```java
public Single<Response> getSomeData(String endpoint, 
        Scheduler scheduler, Consumer<? super Disposable> dispose) {

    Callable<Response> requestor = makeNewRequest(endpoint);
    SingleSubject<Response> result = SingleSubject.create();
    Disposable d = scheduler.scheduleDirect(() -> {
         try {
             result.onSuccess(requestor.call());
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             result.onError(ex);
         }
    });
    if (dispose != null) {
        dispose.accept(d);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note though that this setup is now truly hot, you have to call `getSomeData()` again to have a fresh request issued to the same endpoint and get a fresh result.

Comment: Why is the explicit scheduling required? Assuming I have a Single to start with, shouldn't I be able to do something such as: `SingleSubject subject = SingleSubject.create(); single.subscribe(subject); return subject;` ?

Comment: It depends on what you try to achieve and if that is actually related to the OP's case or not.

Comment: Yeah, that's me (the OP). That's why I'm asking :)